# How to display Serial Numbers with mysql query result in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to display serial numbers beside my mysql query result , example:

```
Serial Number      Name          Country
  1.                John           USA
  2.                Srijon           UK
```

I have tried something with PHP Loops, but I couldn't make it work. Would you please kindly help me?
please note that the serial numbers are not values retrieved from database.

Thanks in Advance :)

```
            <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
            <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Batch Name</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Batch Instructor</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($records as $row){?>

            <tr>

              <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>batch/<?php echo $row['batchid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['batchname'];?></a> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['batchinstructor'];?></td>

            </tr>

        <?php   } ?>

            </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php } ?>
            <div> <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> </div>
```

Comment: Where are the serial numbers stored? Also, are you sure you've posted the relevant code? You state that you want to list serial numbers, names, and countries, but in your code you have batch instructors, classes, and batch names/id's.

Comment: Sorry, If I couldn't explain it clearly. The serial number are not stored anywhere, I want it to be generate automatically by counting the number of rows I have in my query result. And, serial numbers, names, and countries were just an example. Actually I want to list- serial number, batchname, class, courseinstructor. Thats it. And I have posted my view file. thanks :)

Comment: So, by "serial numbers" you mean you want numbered rows?

Comment: yes. Let me describe it more, I have fetched data of column batchname, class, courseinstructor from the table "batch". Now when I am displaying those data I want to display a serial number beside like.. 1,2,3,4.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears (from your example and comments) that by "serial number" you simply want numbered rows. To dynamically number your rows, you can add a counter to your `foreach()` that increments with each record:

```
<?php
    $row_count = 1;
    foreach ($records as $row){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_count;?>.</td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>batch/<?php echo $row['batchid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['batchname'];?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['batchinstructor'];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php $row_count++; } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.:) But the code you posted generates serial numbers like- 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1... but I want it to be like this- 1,2,3,4,5,6... .thanks again for you help :)

Comment: @Srijon: My apologies. The `$row_count` increment should be *inside* the `foreach()`. I edited my answer and it should be working now.

Comment: @ Colin Thank you very very much. :) It is working perfectly now. thanks again for you big help. :)

Comment: @ Colin . Your script works fine till I am on the first page but when I move on to the next page(I am using pagination library) it stops working. it happens like this> when I load my view for the first time- it is like this.. 1.2.3.4.5 but when I move to the next page it starts count from 1 again and it appears like this..1,2,3,5 which supposed to count after 5 from the previous page and appear like this> 6,7,8,9,10.   Would you please kindly take a look at this?? Thanks again :)

Comment: The `$row_count` counter will reset on any subsequent page load. There is no mechanism in the above code that persists the count across pages/views. If you want to maintain a count across pages, depending on how your application is setup, you could store the order number in the database alongside your other data, and then simply `echo` the order number like `echo $row['order_number']`. If you have a specific question about implementing this, it's best to start a new question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

as what i understand that you need a serial number for the view in table.

Once i have same task so i use below example:

```
 <?php if (count($developer_table)): ?> 
                    <?php $count = 0; ?> <-- add this
                        <?php foreach ($developer_table as $developer_table) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= ++$count ?></td><-- First column
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..work like this..1,2,3,4,5

```
$i = 0
while($condition)
{
    echo $i++;
}
```